# Converting List<String> to TreeMap<Long, CustomClass> java lambda

Tags: java, lambda, treemap

I'm trying to convert a `List<String>` to a `TreeMap<Long, CustomClass>` The key is the same as the list items but just parsed to `Long`, the value is just a call to `new CustomClass()`. How can I achieve this using lambda functions?

```
List<String> list = List.of("1","2","3");
TreeMap<Long, CustomClass> resultMap = list.stream()
                                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> Long.parseLong(i), v -> new CustomClass()));
```

the above code errors out, with the following error,

```
Required type:    TreeMap<Long,CustomClass>
Provided:         Map<Object,Object>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) K, U exist so that Map<K, U> conforms to TreeMap<Long, CustomClass>
```

Comment: I think this [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) method may be more appropriate. Your code simply creates a collection of `Long`. I also suggest that you [edit] your question and post the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
final Map<Long, CustomClass> result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Long::valueOf, ignore -> new CustomClass(), (x, y) -> y, TreeMap::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = List.of("1","2","3");
HashMap<Long, CustomClass> map =
list.stream()        
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(i->Long.parseLong(i),v->new CustomClass()));
TreeMap<Long, CustomClass> resultMap =new TreeMap(map);
```

Not tested, but should give you an idea.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this, converting the `map`'s type to `Map<Long, CustomClass>` fixed the code. And then I was creating a `TreeMap` from that.